# Reset count in method by button

Tags: java, javafx

I'm tyring to make a button that starts method with simple timer that count from 5 to 0 and that's it. 
But my problem is when i click the button multiple times the method speeds up the timer and break it.

In the final form this button must every time when it is clicked  should reset the countdown.

```
public class Buttons extends TimerTask {


int delay = 1000;
int period = 1000;
static Timer timer;
static int interval =10;


public static void setTimer(Label label) {

    System.out.println("timer start");
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(interval > 0)
            {
                Platform.runLater(() -> label.setText("TIME TO OVERHEAT: "+interval));
                System.out.println(interval);
                interval--;

            }
            else
                timer.cancel();
        }

    }, 1000,1000);



}
```

Comment: I think it's because you are assigning new timer instances for every click of the button, so it seems like it's speeding up because multiple timers are subtracting from `interval`.  You can test this by printing to the console instead of changing text so you can see if there are multiple "TIME TO OVERHEAT" or not

Comment: It looks like you are operating on the interval which is a static value and it is operated by multiple Timer Tasks. Each new task is decreasing the same `interval`.

Comment: It's better to use a `Timeline` for this, which doesn't start a new thread and so uses less resources and obviates the need for `Platform.runLater()`. You can then enable/disable the button depending on the [`status`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Animation.html#statusProperty) of the timeline.